# Find a negation of formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

What is negation of this formula:

$(A \Rightarrow (B \lor C)) \land (\neg B \Rightarrow D) \land ((D \land A) \Rightarrow \neg C) \Rightarrow B$

I tried to find negation and got this:

$(A \land \neg(B \lor C)) \land (\neg B \land \neg D) \land ((D \land A) \Rightarrow \neg C) \Rightarrow B$

But seems like it's wrong and i don't know what to do next. Could you write down a process of obtaining negation of this formula?

Comment: Just put a negation in front of it .....

Comment: @Bram28 That's true...

Comment: @ryang I was facetious of course ... but also half serious:  I really don't like these questions of 'negate the sentence': either specify what properties the resulting sentence to have (e.g. some kind of normal form) or accept a flippant answer like mine.

Comment: "Oh, I don't think that's allowed. [no elaboration]" $\quad$ @Bram28: "Alright; then add three negations in front."

Comment: @ryang LOL!! You got it :P

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \neg\{(A \to(B \lor C)) \land (\neg B \to D) \land ((D \land A) \to\neg C) \to B \} \\
\iff & \neg\{\neg[(A \to(B \lor C)) \land (\neg B \to D) \land ((D \land A) \to\neg C)] \lor B\}  \\
\iff & (A \to(B \lor C)) \land (\neg B \to D) \land ((D \land A) \to\neg C) \land \neg B
\end{align}